# how to auto-focus programmatically material ui - formik form textfield. with react - typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

i am trying to auto focus my textField, i have applied 'autoFocus' but it only works after i submit the form and value is added, if there are no values added (i.e. the first time we open miui modal) we don't get the autoFocus in textField.

so, i was trying to implement aufocus programmatically using useRef, but it doesn't seem to work as well.

```
 const inputInitialFocus = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      const inputFocus = inputInitialFocus.current as any;
      inputFocus.focus();
    }, 100);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, []);



 <TextField
     className={classes.textField}
     inputRef={inputInitialFocus}
     autoFocus
     fullWidth
     name="ipAddress"
     label={<span className={classes.label}>IP Address</span>}
     variant="standard"
     value={formik.values.ipAddress}
     onChange={formik.handleChange}
     error={formik.touched.ipAddress && Boolean(formik.errors.ipAddress)}
     helperText={formik.touched.ipAddress && formik.errors.ipAddress}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    useEffect(() => {
            // code to run on component mount
          }, [])
```

You could use this, which will only run once when your function first loads, this works as ComponentDidMount() does on components, and you can set your .focus() within this block without all the timeout stuffs. Possibly an easy fix if this works for your use case, and then the autofocus can handle focusing after subsequent submissions.

Comment: but then it is showing me error - 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')'